# eclipse basic methods documentation not showing

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I have had this problem for a while. The methods in classes like String or date in eclipse do not have documentation, and when the suggestions pop up, the methods' names appear but their arguments are all like arg0 , arg1 etc... But this problem seems to be only in eclipse, in netbeans the docs and args are showing correctly.

I am using jdk 1.8.0_05.

this is what it looks like in eclipse

[image]

A comparison:

[image: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/50/1418459824-nojavadoceclipse.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to go into the source code of jdk, e.g. `java.lang.String`, maybe eclipse didn't find the source code.

If you can't go into source code, then make sure your eclipse project is using a jdk that has source code, other than the default ones from eclipse itself which don't contain source code by default.

If the above case is your case, then try download a jdk from oracle, install it, then in eclipse, config jdk installations, and set your project to use that new jdk.

If you don't want to install another jdk by hand, you can find the src.zip file from internet, then copy to local, and specify the location in eclipse.

Comment: where is it supposed to be located?

Comment: @Ariadenus If you download jdk (not jre) from oracle, it should contain the source code, after installation it's located at "$JAVA_HOME/src.zip"

Comment: I do not have that file!!

Comment: @Ariadenus Yeah, that's why you can't see source code ;) , better download a jdk from oracle.